# How to use 'mutable' correctly so the set iterator won't be const?

Tags: c++, class, error-handling, constants

I'm trying to remove the employee in my code and change his salary back to 0, but all I get in the function is his id. I used the built in iterator for the set, but found out that it is const. How can I use mutable, or some other way to change his salary to 0?
I have an employee and a manager- the manager can hire or fire the employee, which will change his salary (obviously).
This is my code:

```
class Manager : public Citizen {
    protected:
        int salary;
        std::set<Employee> employees;

void removeEmployee(const int id) {
            mutable std::set<Employee>::iterator employee;

            for (employee = this->employees.begin(); employee != this->employees.end(); employee++) {
                if (employee->getId() == id) {
                    employee->setSalary(0);
                    this->employees.erase(employee);
                    return;
                }
            }
            throw EmployeeNotHired();
        }
```

And the error I'm getting-

```
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\hw2Cpp\Manager.h:53:50: error: non-member 'employee' cannot be declared 'mutable'
             mutable std::set<Employee>::iterator employee;
                                                  ^~~~~~~~
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\hw2Cpp\Manager.h:57:42: error: passing 'const mtm::Employee' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
                     employee->setSalary(0);
```

What should I do?

**** edit****
I tried changing it to:

```
class Employee : public Citizen {
protected:
    mutable int salary;
    mutable int score;
    std::set<Skill> skills;
```

But I am still unable to change the salary to 0.

```
error: passing 'const mtm::Employee' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
                     employee->setSalary(0);
```

Comment: `mutable` only applies to member variables, not local variables.

Comment: @Sean so what can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of `std::set` ensures that elements of the set "cannot be modified" i.e. they can only be accessed via const references. This is for a good reason: `std::set` relies on the order of its elements remaining the same thoughout the lifetime to maintain its internal search tree datastructure.

Ways to deal with this are:

1. declaring `setSalary` as a const member function. (Not a good idea since setting the salary probably does modify the object in a way that wouldn't be expected of a const function.)
2. [Extract](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract) the employee (C++17)

   ```
   //employee->setSalary(0);
   //this->employees.erase(employee);
   auto node = employees.extract(employee);
   node.value().setSalary(0);
   ```
3. Choose a different data structure such as a `std::unordered_map<int, Employee>` mapping from id to `Employee` or `std::vector<Employee>`.

However unless the `setSalary` function has effects other than modifying the `Employee` object, just remove the object from the set; The object is deleted in the process anyways...

Answer (score 3):

That's not how it works. You can change a value through a const reference, if the *member* is marked mutable (`mutable int salary;`) not the iterator.

However, why do you want to set the salary to zero just before you delete it? And anyway, changing values in a set is not allowed if it affects the order of that set, so generally a bad idea.

Comment: I tried changing it but still no luck. And I need to change it so that he could be hired by other places

Comment: The set stores a *copy* of the Employee record, and that copy disappears at the  erase-call. Anyway, to call `setSalary` on a const object, the function must also be marked `const`. However, having a `const` fucntion that changes member values is extremely odd., and a big code smell.